# How to get a 2007 stylye breadcrumb on 2010 settings pages?

Tags: navigation

I've modified the breadcrumb on my master page to mimic the breadcrumb style from 2007 by copying the 2007 code over:

```
<span class="ms-mwstitlearea">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
        <asp:SiteMapPath SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" ID="ContentMap" SkipLinkText="" CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrent" NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-sitemapdirectional" runat="server" />&nbsp;
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</span>
```

However, on the site settings pages, the breadcrumb turns into a hybrid of 2007 and 2010 styles where it's vertically listed with right arrow images between the levels. How can I change the site settings pages to use the 2007 breadcrumb style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this. The *.aspx pages under 14/TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS contain a section which sets the breadcrumb to the 2007 style if SP2010 is set to the 2007 look and feel, and to the 2010 style otherwise. I'm going through those pages and changing the breadcrumb code to only use the 2007 style.